# Importing Facebook friends to different social network: How to know which friends are which?

Tags: facebook, social-networking

It is straightforward to retrieve a list of friends from Facebook using their api.

But how would a site figure out which of its members corresponds to the Facebook friend it has imported?

Is there a unique id that could be used? For example, does Facebook give the email address of the friend, so that could be compared to see if a person with the same email address is a member of the social network?

If not, how would you address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't expose the email address directly, since it needs to be sure that you can no longer contact a user after they remove your application. However, they use a hash of the email address to identify which of your existing members correspond to Facebook users.

First you need to tell Facebook about your members using [Connect.registerUsers](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect.registerUsers), then you can retrieve the email hashes of user's friends with a bit of FQL...

```
SELECT uid, email_hashes, has_added_app
FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = XXX )
```